# Why am I getting this error when trying to add a new site in Apache?

Tags: apache2

I'm trying to do some PHP work, and decided to install LAMP. I've followed the instructions on [this Ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP#To_install_the_default_LAMP_stack_in_Ubuntu_10.04_and_above) to install, and also add an extra site (using /var/wwww and having to gksu nautilus files seemed pointless) so I followed the instructions here under "Virtual Hosts".

However, I completed the instructions and when I try and restart Apache I get the following message:

```
dan@inn0min4t3:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
Syntax error on line 4 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite:
DocumentRoot takes one argument, Root directory of the document tree
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

And this is my mysite config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /home/dan/Documents/Website Design/helheimr
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /home/dan/Documents/Website Design/helheimr/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Sorry if it's obvious. I spent a while looking on Google and I couldn't find much, I did read that I might need to remove the `/` at the end, and I tried that but I had the same result.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't it the space in `DocumentRoot /home/dan/Documents/Website Design/helheimr`?

There are two arguments:

- `/home/dan/Documents/Website`
- `Design/helheimr`.

Maybe just rename `Website Design` to `WebsiteDesign`, adjust the Apache config file, and reload Apache config file.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I just realised that as well. Now I'm getting an updated error, but that was because of double quotes also.

Comment: If anyone got here from windows side of WAMP, this was also the same answer to my problem. There was a project that got added with a space in the folder path and removing it fixed it.